# SSL keeps waiting for response

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl, https, letsencrypt

I'm trying to configure an HTTPS but It doesn't work and I don't realy know what's wrong.

These are the steps I've followed:

1. I have generated a `.pem` certificate (certificate + chain) with [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), by using the next command:

   `sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --server https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`

The response comes in this way:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem. Your cert
   will expire on 2016-03-07. To obtain a new version of the
   certificate in the future, simply run Let's Encrypt again.
 - If like Let's Encrypt, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

2. I have generated a private key

   `sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem -keyout /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.key`

Here bellow I paste the response:

```
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:xxxx
Locality Name (eg, city) []:xxxx
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:xxxx
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:xxxx.com
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:test
Email Address []:test@gmail.com
```

3. I have checked that the key returns the correct value I've set in the last step:

   `sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem -noout -subject`

Here bellow I paste the response:

```
subject= /C=US/ST=xxxx/L=xxxx/O=xxxx/OU=xxxx.com/CN=test/
emailAddress=test@gmail.com
```

4. I've set a new virtual host that I copy here bellow:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxx1/public
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
     ServerName xxxx.com
     SSLEngine on

     SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.key

     <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
     </FilesMatch>

     <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
     </Directory>

     BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
       BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. I've opened 443 port on my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.

After all these steps, I've just do `sudo service apache2 restart` but the console is just waiting till I get:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and when I debug it with `journalctl -xe` the result is what it comes:

```
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Dec 08 19:12:20 devXxxx apache2[21637]: * Starting web server apache2
Dec 08 19:12:20 devXxxx apache2[21637]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 100.114.32.17. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this mes
Dec 08 19:12:20 devXxxx apache2[21637]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
Dec 08 19:12:29 devXxxx sudo[21613]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 08 19:12:29 devXxxx polkitd(authority=local)[996]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:21628:9475994 (system bus name :1.109, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, loca
Dec 08 19:12:40 devXxxx apache2[21637]: *
Dec 08 19:12:40 devXxxx apache2[21637]: * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
Dec 08 19:12:40 devXxxx systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 08 19:12:40 devXxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
```

After watching these 20 seconds that apache is trying to load, I've decided to test the certificate as I detail:

1. Checking there is only 1 certificate:

   `sudo ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem`sudo openssl x509 -hash -noout -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem`.0`
2. Verifying that the certificate works:

   `openssl verify -CApath f6361f65.0`

but surprise, it doesn't.... the terminal keeps trying to connect without response.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it looks like something is already bound to port `443`:

> Dec 08 19:12:20 devXxxx apache2[21637]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
>   D

Next, with Lets Encrypt, you don't need to setup your own private key, the script should generate one for you (unless you manually generate your own CSR).

When the `letsencrypt-auto` script completes you should have in your certificate directory 4 files.

- `cert.pem` - This is your certificate.  In Apache `SSLCertificateFile` should point to this file.
- `privkey.pem` - This is your private key. KEEP IT SECRET.  In Apache `SSLCertificateKeyFile` should point to this file.
- `chain.pem` - This is the chain of certificates that establish your trust.  In Apache you can point `SSLCertificateChainFile` to this file.
- `fullchain.pem` - This is a combination of `cert.pem` and `chain.pem`, so it is your certificate and its full chain of trust.  In Apache point `SSLCACertificateFile` to this file.

[Let's Encrypt Documentation](https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#where-are-my-certificates)

Comment: The file usage is slightly outdated and slightly wrong. `SSLCertificateChainFile` is deprecated and Apache 2.4 would rather read the chain from the certificate file, like most other programs do. Thus **`SSLCertificateFile fullchain.pem`**. Meanwhile, `SSLCACertificateFile` has nothing to do with this _at all_ – the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile) emphasizes that this option is only relevant for _client_ authentication, so putting any LE cert there is wrong & useless.

Comment: Just adding that in Apache 2.4 is not necesary anymore in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` the line: `Listen 443`. Instead just specify in the `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

Answer (score 0):

For letsencypt this command works for me without stopping the server

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --webroot -w /websitedir -d www.domain.com
```

after this process for nginx you can link the certificates.

```
ln -s privkey.pem /etc/ssl/domain.key
ln -s fullchain.pem /etc/ssl/domain.crt
```